# How to Pass Environment Variable defined in Buildspec to Groovy Script as Argument In Build Phase

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, devops, aws-codebuild, groovyshell

I am Calling Groovy file In Build Command of the buildspec.yml and Would Like to Initialize An Variable in the Groovy script with An Environment Variable defined in Buildspec. How to get the Argument and initialize Variable with the Argument inside groovy.
Below is my groovy script and Command.

groovysh check.groovy $fileNameList

```
import hudson.model.*


def nameList=fileNameList.tokenize(',')
def finalNameList=[]
for (i=0 ; i< nameList.size();i++)
{
println(nameList[i])
def sonarname="**/*"+nameList[i]+".html"
println(sonarname)
finalNameList.add(sonarname)
}
println(finalNameList)
String result = finalNameList.join(",")
def map = [sonarNameList: result]
println(map)
println(Sonar_Analysis)
return map
```

Need Initialize Variable fileNameList with Environment Variable $fileNameList defined in Buildspec.yml
How to Implement this

Comment: Can anyone please assist !

Answer (score 0):

Define an environment variable in your buildspec and pass it to your function. You can then set your environment variables in CodeBuild console.

```
  env:
    variables:
       fileNameList: "abc, def"

  build:
    commands:
      - groovysh check.groovy ${fileNameList}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse , I Tried the Above method and got the below exception.

Comment: [Container] 2019/08/28 06:53:26 Running command groovysh Check.groovy ${fileNameList} 
Aug 28, 2019 6:53:27 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run 
INFO: Created user preferences directory. 
FATAL: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: US_BHCP_OPD_NPPINDICATIONS_201906_01 for class: groovysh_evaluate 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: US_BHCP_OPD_NPPINDICATIONS_201906_01 for class: groovysh_evaluate

Comment: sorry, I can't help with that. I've never used groovy.